# How to restart every scenes including the progress in unity game engine?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm creating a simple 2D game in Unity. I've successfully completed every part, but the restart button is pending.

I tried using this code:

```
currentSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
```

or

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("floor1");
```

But this code doesn't restart every progress I made. For example, I created a variable called key1 in the script. It becomes true when I collide with that game object.

So, if I reload with the given code, the value of key remains true, but I need it to be in its initial value, which is false.

Is there any other way than changing the value to false? Because there are too many similar objects like the key.

Comment: all elements within the scene are reloaded, unless you specifically coded them not to (donotdestroy) so, you control that, if "key1" whatever the heck that is, is not changing then you have made it do so

Comment: sound like that key1 is a PlayerPref key.
if yes, you can remove that key PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll(); -> this will delete all your player prefs.

Comment: `I created a variable called key1 in the script.`. Show us the class.

Answer (score 0):

Scene instances (and their data) are reset upon reloading a `scene` in Unity. As @BugFinder mentioned, the only reason this wouldn't happen is if your instance data is `static` or if [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) was called on them.

Just to remove any confusion, the code:

```
currentSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex
```

does not reload your `scene`, but gets the `scene`'s`buildIndex`.

### If you can't change your existing framework..

then you could add a *delegate* to [SceneManager.sceneLoaded](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneLoaded.html) to update any data upon a loading a `scene`.